# import python code to Unity

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, import, export, dllimport

I need to import [this python project](https://github.com/marcellacornia/sam) to Unity3d. How can i do that? Based on my search, i see that there are plugins like [this](https://github.com/exodrifter/unity-python). However, i need to perform this tasks without using any plugin? How should i do that, i am experienced in Unity but i have no python experience? Can i get .dlls from python project so that i can use the .dlls in Unity. Or should i do something else?

If someone lead me, i'd appereciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can. I know that's not what you're looking for, and don't let me discourage you, but start looking for another answer. I've been trying for a while now, and even *with* plugins the best I could do cost about $40, and that guy spent about a year working on it. Maybe try manually converting it to C#?

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'll keep searching. if i could find something, i'll add here.

Comment: No problem. BTW I just looked at your python project: very profound!

Comment: yes, i guess it is hard and deep :( it is an implemenetation of mesh saliency method. unfortunately, i've no python experience.

Comment: do you think is it possible to call python code from c++ and call c++ code from unity(i know the latter is possible, but i am not sure how 2 external nested calls would be appropriate)

Comment: I don't think so. You could execute a python script, but for it to actually control game objects, you would need unity integration. Although you COULD have python write to a file, then go from there...

Comment: what i meant is providing unity integration via c++ which calls python code? (maybe i couldn't exactly tell what i meant)

Comment: Yah I know I was saying it's not possible and trying to give other ways

Comment: ok then, i couldn't get (: what i am planning is(if possible) applying unity integration by calling c++, in that case, if i succeed, i would control game objects?

Comment: You can only control game objects with c code, not python, but c code could make python do OTHER things. What I suggest is having your python script write it's output to a file, and use c code to read the file and control the game objects